# Где хранится префаб: на диске или в ram памяти, если в сцене есть хотя бы одна ссылка не него?

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-editor, unity3d-faq

В проекте есть префаб, в сцене присутствует хотя бы одна ссылка на него, условно:

```
...
public GameObject prefab;
...
```

**Вопрос**: в какой памяти хранится данный объект?

Comment: у вас остались какие-то вопросы?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы не гадать, сделаем бенчмарк, благо у Unity отличный профайлер.

Что показывает профайлер на **абсолютно пустой** сцене:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Создадим какой-то рандомный префаб и накидаем на него какие-то скрипты. Добавим пустой объект с простым скриптом, который ссылается на этот префаб. Открываем дебаггер:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На самом деле почти все эти цифры нестабильны, но за параметры кол-во мешей и материалов мы можем быть спокойны и судить по ним: при референсе префаба с **1 материалом** и **несколькими  мешами**(первая попавшаяся модель с гугла) выросли значения:

1. *Meshes*: 73 -> 77 (**+4 меши**)
2. *Materials*: 50 -> 51 (**+1 материал**)
3. *Общая память Unity*: 329.0MB -> 333.8MB (**+4.8MB**), не самая надежная цифра, но все же показатель

---

### Ответ

Исходя из данных выше, можно сделать следующий вывод:

1. Если префаб инстанциируется через ссылку - Unity подгружает **во время загрузки сцены**

   ```
   Instantiate(prefab_reference);
   ```
2. Если префаб инстанциируется через папку ресурсов - Unity подгрузит его **перед инстанциированием**, причем рекурсивно

   ```
   Instantiate(Resources.Load("Prefabs/PrefabNameHere"));
   ```
3. Если *префаб номер 1* загружается с диска и при этом ссылается на *префаб номер 2* - *префаб номер 2* будет подгружен при загрузке *префаба номер 1*

Причем во всех 3х ситуациях префабы будут грузится рекурсивно, пока в памяти не окажутся все, очевидно, **уникальные** объект, на которые есть ссылки.

---

### Важно!

**Префаб будет загружен полностью, а не по кускам**, все компоненты сразу, а не только голый `Transform` с последующей подгрузкой оставшихся компонентов. Чисто теоретически об этом говорит графа `Total Objects in Scene`, которая выросла с **205 до 218**.

Comment: Очень полезно =)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ объемный туман

Comment: нет я не писал =) это я года 2 назад сделал и лежит без дела

Answer (score 0):

> Префаб - это один из типов ресурсов, предназначений для многократного
>   использования и хранящийся в Project View. Префаб может быть вставлен
>   в любое количество сцен и многократно в одну сцену. Когда префаб
>   добавляется в сцену, создаётся его экземпляр. Все экземпляры являются
>   ссылками на оригинальный префаб и фактически его клонами. Независимо
>   от того, как много экземпляров в проекте, при изменении префаба
>   изменяются соответственно и все его экземпляры.

[Документация](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/Prefabs.html)

Comment: так я и не понял, загрузить он с диска или при старте сцены будет добавлен полностью в оперативную память?

Comment: @kovpack не знаю точно когда он полностью займет место в пямяти, когда загружается сцена или когда он первый раз попадет во фрустум(это может быть по-разному реализовано в движке), но определенно ему надо быть в памяти, чтобы отрисовываться-обсчитываться

Comment: быть то он будет, а будут ли его компоненты с ним, большую часть же занимает его меш.